# How do I execute a nested aggregation in Elasticsearch inside of a Go app?

Tags: go, elasticsearch

I'm working on an application we're writing in Go, and the application needs to pull some statistics over time. I want to pull some data from a monitoring index we have and group it first by time, and then by the different statuses that the monitor can return at a given point in time.

E.g., for something that's logging the response code when hitting a particular URL, I'd like to get an aggregation first by time slice and then with summary counts for 200, 400, 403, etc. status codes.

How do I do that using the [Elastic package](https://github.com/olivere/elastic/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things to know here. First, I found it easiest to work out how the package works by looking at the test code in the package. That's how I found the two aggregations I needed, `NewAutoDateHistogramAggregation` and `NewTermsAggregation`.

For the nested aggregation, you can achieve that by chaining the sub aggregation onto the first one.

We first create the `statusAgg` object (the sub-aggregation), and then chain that on as we set up the parent aggregation against time. Note passing in the `statusAgg` to the `SubAggregation` chained onto the date histogram aggregation.

Then to execute the aggregation, only the parent aggregation is actually passed to the search context, and the return has the results nested as you would expect.

```
statusAgg := elastic.NewTermsAggregation().Field("statuscode")
timeAgg := elastic.NewAutoDateHistogramAggregation().
    Field("@timestamp").
    SubAggregation("status", statusAgg)

result, err := es.Search().
    Index(index).
    Query(boolQuery).
    Aggregation("time", timeAgg).
    Size(0).
    Pretty(true).
    Do(ctx)
```